# url rewriting an id with a string variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

trying to figure out how to rewrite this url clientside

```
blog.com/post/how-to-get-the-ladies
```

to point serverside to

```
blog.com/post.php?id=123
```

i know how to do this:

```
blog.com/post/123

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

but how do you replace the id string with the post title slug?

Comment: How will it know to map 'how-to-get-the-ladies' to 123?

Comment: well, thats my question.  i know blogs like wordpress give you this option.  wondering if they use mod-rewrite or simply structure the url to include the title slug...

Comment: As explained in the answers, no they don't use mod_rewrite for this.

Comment: ok i realize it's a combination of rewrite + php (for me).  found this article...think this is what i want to do but can't bridge the gap and figure out what i need to do...

http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/clean-urls-for-a-better-search-engine-ranking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webserver itself doesn't make this distinction and cannot translate from your "unique text identifier" to the database id. Therefore a .htaccess rule alone evaluated by the webserver will not help you. But how is it done on all those web-applications? Normally this translation is done by Joomla/Wordpress itself and it only works as long the "how_to_get_the_ladies" text is known and unique throughout the system/database.

Comment: Joomla/Wordpress are only examples, of course - the point being that it's done in the web application (in PHP/Python/Perl etc.), not in .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

you can add rule that go to index file like :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

and in this file according to the title you can show the post that request

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem recently. I would suggest looking into the RewriteMap directive and using an 'External Rewriting Program'.

There are some big limitations with RewriteRule in terms of maintainability and robustness. If you haven't gotten there yet you may eventually. Only simple rewriting rules can be written safely.

With a rewriteMap you can create a php or perl script, take advantage of your existing code base, and perform all the rewriting rules from a localized place in your code which easily sits in version control.

I believe you need access to the httpd.conf (or vhost) configuration file though, RewriteMaps (or some related directive) cannot be put in .htaccess files.